# Replacing keyword argument in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I am doing some testing and I would like to mock one argument of a function.

For example I got function like:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    'do something'
```

and call of that function:

```
foo(1, 2)
```

I would like to monkeypatch it somehow to use 3 instead of 2. Is that possible?

tried something like:

```
monkeypatch.setattr('foo', partial(foo, arg2= 3))
```

But I got type error: foo() got multiple values for keyword argument 'arg2'

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: It seems you are testing foo indirectly, and you are trying to modify the call to foo. Please edit to show: 1. `def test_bar`, 2. where `foo` is called (`bar` perhaps?), in addition to the `def foo`. You should probably be testing foo directly and then using dependency injection in `bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply alias the function:

```
old_foo = monkeypatch.foo
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    return old_foo(arg1, 3)

monkeypatch.foo = foo
```